# Laravel blade.php page prints the PHP code instead of running it

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

When I load a page in the browser it literally displays all the PHP and HTML code instead of running it, why doesn't the if statement works?
its a .blade.php page in the public folder with only HTML code. The code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
@if (session->has('email'))
    <p>Show this paragraph.</p>
@else
    <p>Show this other paragraph.</p>
@endif
```

The HTML page was well formed and working correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"> 
    various html elements
</html>
```

It's my first time with blade and php. Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Show us the part of the controller where you render the template?

Comment: Public folder? it should be in resources > views

Comment: I don't have a controller, since it's in the public folder It's available just like any other file. @NoOorZ24, that's way it doesn't run PHP?  With a  quick search about the public and resources folders I didn't get any big reasons to use one instead of the other, it sounded like it was up to preference.

Comment: @TiagoS It's not up to preference. Templates go in `resources/views`. Doesn't matter if you're using a controller or not - by putting it in `public` you bypass **all** of Laravel. You're just writing raw PHP that way, and Blade *isn't* PHP, so PHP has no idea what to do with `@if`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blade templates (all templates, really, but *especially* Blade) need to go in `resources/views`, not `public`. The Blade template language isn't understood by PHP - it's only interpreted if it's processed through Laravel's view system, i.e. `return view('name.of.template')`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it happens when we create view's template filename without using `blade.php` as extension. eg. If we want to make a blade template file in `resources/views` directory for `adduser` action then blade template file name will be `adduser.blade.php`. Thanks for asking this question.